# Write JTextArea Text as String

Tags: java, textarea, bufferedwriter

NOTE: Thanks to [user2602219](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602219/user2602219) and [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson)  I've solved my problem. I wish I could approve both answers right and vote up.

I've searched a lot. I've found something but they were not suitable for me.

All I want is write

```
Hello
World
```

as seen. But in my txt file it shows HelloWorld

```
    try{
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        String path = folder+"/"+name+".txt";
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
        area.write(output);
        output.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){}
```

The code above works fine. However, I've to do something before writing.

I've an encryption method (called enc). It takes a string and replaces letters wit another letters.

For example:

```
String text = "ABC";
String enc_text = enc(text);
```

//enc_text is now "ZXW";

But here is the thing. JTextArea.write looks for a "Writer" but I have to write a string because my encrypter returns a string.

Long story short. How to make

```
Hello
World
```

to this

```
Gteeu 
Wuazx
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `setText` method?

Comment: u need to encrypt the string?

Comment: no guys come on. when I write to a file as string, it removes new lines. when I write by using JTextArea.write, I can't use my encryption method. All I need is use a method like JTextArea.write but takes an argument as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take the unencrypted string from the first text area.
2. Encrypt it.
3. Put the encrypted string in a second text area that is not immediately visible to the end user.
4. Use the `JTextCompnent.write(..)` method on the encrypted text area.

Comment: I want to thank you for helping about my question. I've solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
String text = "Hello" + "\nWorld";
```

\n is a new line.

Comment: The text comes from JTextArea and user writes something. Thanks for your answer but this can't help me. But if you can tell me how to replace all JTextArea new line generated by user with \n it'll solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

static void writeStringToFile(File file, String data) 
which allows you to write text to a file in one method call.

or use
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("test.txt"), "Hello File");

Comment: I need to write it to a file as you can see some part of my code

Comment: So you're asking how to write text to a file?  I thought the question was something to do with `JTextArea`.  Please clarify what you're asking!

Comment: Maybe you didn't get the question? Why would I need IO commands if I don't want to write a text file? What's about my "path" variable? Why to use BufferedWriter? This guy clearly wants to write to a text file.

Comment: that's the problem. You want a "String" data argument but when I convert JTextArea's text to string I'm losing lines.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to read each line separately and then write it on the desired txt file? This way you could use "\n" to write on a new line. Another solution that came to my mind is using the following method:
String s = "";
s = s.format(something + "\n");

This way you would have lines in the string itself :)

Comment: no. actually it may be what I need. but like I said, I have to encrypt text. So basically, I have to get JTextArea's text to a string (it has to be only one string) and ecrypt it. And then write encrypted text to a txt file.

Comment: It might be a weird solution, but did you think of adding the encrypted character to the file as soon as its added to the JTextArea? And you can place a KeyListener to add a "\n" whenever the user uses the enter/return key?

Comment: Yes I thought about that. When pressed enter on JTextArea, write (for example) #. And then replace all # chars with \n. It may disturb user but if I can't found another way out I have to do this. Can we add a new line to JTextArea and a character by pressing enter? User needs to see new line, I have to add a character. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: I want to thank you for helping about my question. I've solved it :)